# Toggle SPAN Class along with this div toggle

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I have tried this several different ways but can't seem to figure out how to toggle the span's class from "die2" to "die3" along with the toggle of the div's display style from 'block' to 'none'. Anybody have any solutions?  (Basically when the page loads, this ad will be displayed and when you click the red x (die2) the add disappears and the red x should change to a green check box (die3).  Here's the code that does work for the div toggle that I'm using.

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:block">
<img src='http://www.test.com/mypopad.png' alt='' />
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="if(document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display == 'block'){ document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'none'; }else{ document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'block'; }"><span id="myspan" class="die2"><!-- --></span></a>
```

Thanks guys, I think I got it going now ... I added another class to the stylsheet and then just reused what JKing answered. I could get the divHide to work but it would just add the class and remove the class.  So I decided to just add a divShow and use the same code for the span.  Thanks guys!

```
<div id="mydiv" class="divShow">
<img src='http://www.northpointemobilehomesales.com/wp-content/gallery/support-images/big-daves-sidebar-ad_03.png' alt='' />
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="document.getElementById('mydiv').classList.toggle('divHide');document.getElementById('mydiv').classList.toggle('divShow');document.getElementById('myspan').classList.toggle('die2');document.getElementById('myspan').classList.toggle('die3');">
<span id="myspan" class="die2"><!-- --></span>
</a>
```

Since the above did not work in IE I Used Sven's code and got it to work, we were missing the # when we called the #mydiv...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function(){
    $("#myspan").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("die2").toggleClass("die3");
      $("#mydiv").toggle();
   });
  });
</script>

<div id="mydiv" class="">
<img src='http://www.northpointemobilehomesales.com/wp-content/gallery/support-images/big-daves-sidebar-ad_03.png' alt='' />
</div>

<a href="#">
<span id="myspan" class="die2"><!-- --></span>
</a>
```

I'll work with this code for a bit and see if it will suite my needs.  :)  Thanks guys!

Comment: Have a look into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This is a framework that can do these things easily for you. [(Tutorials)](http://w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function(){
    $("#myspan").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("die2").toggleClass("die3");
      $("#mydiv").toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

That's it

Comment: I"m assuming I would implement this like: <a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggle()"><span id="myspan" class="die2"><!-- --></span>
</a>  If so, it does the same as the other code, it toggles the die2 to die3 but also does not hide or collapse the div.  It does not hide the class name either when I view it in firebug. Thanks, by the way for everyone's quick responses.

Comment: you must link in the header at first jquery and after insert this script, for this solution. you don't need an event in the html, because you bind the click event directly in the script to the element

Comment: Ok I gotcha but it still only changes the die2 to die3 but doesn't not toggle the div on and off.  Nevermind, there's an error in the toggle part, it should be #mydiv ... lol  :) It also seems to be working in IE as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery, though you might like it. All you need to do is use an element's `classList` object. 
You can do a lot of cool things with `classList`:

```
el.classList.add("myClassName")      //adds class (does nothing if el already has that class)
el.classList.remove("myClassName")   //removes class (does nothing if el doesn't have that class)
el.classList.toggle("myClassName")   //toggles class 

el.classList.contains("myClassName") //returns true if el has that class, false if not.
```

Here's a modified version of your code, as an example of what you could do - though I'm not sure it's exactly what you want to do, but it should point you in the right direction.

```
<div id="mydiv" class="divHide">
    <img src='http://www.test.com/mypopad.png' alt='' />
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="document.getElementById('mydiv').classList.toggle('divHide');document.getElementById('myspan').classList.toggle('die2');document.getElementById('myspan').classList.toggle('die3');">
    <span id="myspan" class="die2"><!-- --></span>
</a>
```

(I'm toggling a class on the div as well to show/hide it, instead of your if/else checking of the style attribute.)

Comment: This almost works and makes sense to me but the divHide has an issue or I'm confused. When I click the link it does change the style for the span from (die2) to (die3), but the divHide only changes the html from <div id="mydiv" class="divHide"> to <div id="mydiv" class="">. It hid the class but did not hide the div.

Comment: Be aware that [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) is not supported in any version of IE (according to the Mozilla Developer Network, though they offer a shim that works in IE8 (and presumably above), as well as other older browsers.

Comment: you'd need to add a css rule for the class divHide:

    div.divHide 
    {
        display:none;
    }

Comment: David Thomas brings up a good point, which is that there are some browsers that lack native support for classList. To remedy this, simply use a polyfill: https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js (much lighter than JQuery, if you don't need any of JQuery's other functionality.)

Comment: It will if you include the that js file I linked in my previous comment. Again, that polyfill is much more lightweight than something like Jquery, if toggling classes is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest jQuery:

`mydiv.toggle() or mydiv.removeClass("die2").addClass("die3")`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough to know how to integrate this into the html in order to test this.  The site does use jquery, it's a wordpress site with a pandatheme ...

Comment: If you tell me how to integrate the jquery example I'll test it out and post it in the question so that others can benefit from this.  Thanks Toudldel.  :)